# Basis change matrix As tensor representation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that an isomorphism between two vector spaces can be represented (under a specific basis) through a square matrix, which in turn is the representation of a rank-2-tensor under that specific basis (please correct me if I am wrong). I also know how the components of a generic tensor transform under a basis change --> using the correct basis-change-Matrix.

My point is: can a generic basis-change-matrix be considered itself a representation of an isomorphism? If so, is there a rank-2-tensor associated with It As well?

Thank you

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might get a better answer at Math.SE.

Comment: Two different vector spaces don’t have “a specific basis”. One chooses a basis for each space independently. You also seem to be using the phrase “tensor representation” in a nonstandard way.

Comment: I'm sorry if I Am not using the correct terms, I try to be more precise. A linear application from a vector space into itself can be represented by a square matrix, which depends of the basis chosen for the representation. Do you agree on this?

Comment: Now, in my understanding, the Matrix elements correspond to the components of a tensor. This tensor, thought As a geometrical object, can be said to represent the isomorphism

Comment: I agree that a linear map from a vector space into itself can be represented by a square matrix, which depends on the basis chosen for the vector space. I would not use the word “representation” to describe that matrix. To me, “representation” is short for “group representation”.

Comment: No, I don’t agree that the matrix elements are tensor components. For example, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/387535/.

Comment: When we talk about vectors, tensors, etc., we are talking about how certain quantities transform under a *group* of transformations of some space. You are talking about *one* transformation. The transformation matrix you are talking about is one of many transformation matrices which are used to transform vectors, tensors, etc. The vectors and tensors are things being transformed, not the matrices doing the transforming.

Comment: I understand your point, but I am not totally convinced yet. Take the inertia tensor for example: It maps one vector (angular velocity) into another vector (angular momentum). So this tensor is associated to an isomorphism. And this isomorphism can be expressed through a square Matrix whose elements depend on the basis chosen.

Comment: Now think to the the change-of-basis Matrix associated to the rotation from an old basis to a new one (which can be used to perform a tensor transformation).The same Matrix can be used to express the isomorphism which maps a vector into a rotated one (expressed in the "old" basis).  So I expect that some tensor exists which is related to such isomorphism. So I deduce that a tensor can be associated to a transformation-Matrix, since they can both be used to describe a specific isomorphism. What is wrong with this reasoning?